# Node.js Doesn't Execute DB Function From Browser

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I have installed Node.js server with the Apache server via proxy mod and it starts fine. When I call the server.js file from console like: `node /var/www/project/node/server.js` I get the running notification message which is: **"ok, server is running"**

And when I go to browser and point to the server.js `http://example.com/node/` I get status 200 and it works.

The problem, the function **test** is executed only when I start the server.js from console, but when I request server.js from browser or via AJAX call, then the function **test** is not executed. I notice that through the database entries.

I would greatly appreciate your feedback. My code is below:

```
var http=require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'xxx',
   password : 'xxx',
   database : 'db_test',  //mysql database to work with (optional)
});
connection.connect(); //connect to mysql

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
     res.end('Connected');
});


server.on('listening',function(){
    console.log('ok, server is running');
});

server.listen(9000);



function test(){
    var s = new Date().getTime();
    connection.query('INSERT INTO table_test.emails (email) VALUES ("'+s+'")',function(err, result) {});
}

test();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I request `server.js` from browser or via AJAX call"?

Comment: I meant when turning the node.js server on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `app.js` is run when you start the server with `node /var/www/project/node/server.js` (The entire file is *not* run for each request, unlike PHP).  You're telling node to listen on port 9000 and execute whatever's in your `createServer` callback when it receives a request.  Thus, you need to put the call to `test()` inside your `createServer` callback for it to work.:

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
  test();
  res.end('Connected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works. Actually I need to make long polling but I am beginner with Node.js. So just to confirm, every function has to be available inside the createServer function? Because I will be calling the function test every 1 second. Is there any way to avoid executing test when turning server.js ON? Thanks.

Comment: @moderns That's already happening.  If you're looking into long-polling, I'd suggest checking out http://socket.io/

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I am not interested in socket.io because it is not compatible with all browsers and versions.